# How to show/hide tab sections using checkboxes with the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have tabs section with 3 sections, Each tab has its own heading and content.

But I don't want to show all the 3 tabs, Just what the user select by checking the related checkbox, There are 3 related checkboxes, One for each tab.

Here is the code:

```js
//Function to hide all siblings but leave the clicked one
function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
 $('#'+parentId).children().css('display', 'none');
 $('#'+toRevealId).css('display', 'block');
}

//Function to show the tab header and content when a checkbox is checked
function showSection(parentId, toRevealId){
 $('#'+parentId).children().css('display', 'none');
 $('#'+toRevealId).css('display', 'block');
 var relatedSection = $('#'+toRevealId).attr('data-section');
 $('#'+relatedSection).css('display', 'block');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //On clicking a tab header('Father', 'Mother', 'Brother')
 $('.tab-header').click(function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('tab_active').siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
  var related_section = $(this).attr('data-section');
  hideAllChildrenButOne('relative_content', related_section);
 });

    //On changing any checkbox with name=relative[]
 $("input[name='relative[]']").change( function () {
     var self = $(this);
     if (self.is(":checked")) {
      showSection('relative_tabs', self.attr('data-header'), self.attr('id'));
     }
 });
 
});
```

```css
.relative_container{
    position: relative;
    padding: 45px 15px 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 15px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
 .relative_container {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #ddd;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
 }
}
.relative_tabs{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 7px 0;
}
.relative_tabs:before{
 display: table;
 content: " ";
} 
.relative_tabs>li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.relative_tabs>li>a{
 margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.relative_tabs>li.tab_active>a{
 color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.relative_content div{
 display: none;
}
.relative_content>div.active{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <label>Father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Father" data-header="father-tab"></label>
 <label>Mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Mother" data-header="mother-tab"></label>
 <label>Brother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Brother" data-header="brother-tab"></label>
 <div class="relative_container">
  <div class="relative_header">
   <ul class="relative_tabs" id="relative_tabs">
    <li id="father-tab" data-section="Father_info" class="tab-header tab_active">
     <a>Father</a>
    </li> 
    <li data-section="Mother_info" class="tab-header" id="mother-tab">
     <a>Mother</a>
    </li>
    <li data-section="Brother_info" class="tab-header" id="brother-tab">
     <a>Brother</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="relative_content" id="relative_content">
   <div class="tab-content active" id="Father_info">Father Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="Mother_info">Mother Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="Brother_info">Brother Info</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Now it's showing one tab on checking any checkbox, So if I check Father checkbox father tab would be shown, Then if I check Mother checkbox mother tab would be shown and father tab would become hidden.

I want to show the tabs of the checked checkboxes only, So if 1 checkbox is checked only the related tab is shown, If 2 checkboxes are checked the related two tabs are shown and the 3rd is hidden..etc.

Of course if the user checks all the checkboxes and then unchecked them, They would become hidden.

Comment: There's no need to post code examples to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just post your code in a "code snippet" right here in your question as I've done for you. Now, if you had looked at your developer's console, you would have seen that your current code is throwing the following error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=relative[]]`.  It's because of this line `$("input[name=relative[]]").change( function () {`, which should be `$("input[name='relative[]']").change( function () {`

Comment: @ScottMarcus, Thanks for improving/fixing the code

Comment: @MrJ Checkbox names do not need to be different. When the same name is used, a comma separated list is submitted with all the values from all the selected checkboxes with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can easily be done by re-writing the `showSection` function. You just need to `toggle` the visibility of the `tabs` everytime a `checkbox` is selected.

```
function showSection(parentId, toRevealId) {
  $('#' + toRevealId).toggle('display');
  if ($('input[data-header=' + toRevealId + ']').is(':checked')) {
    $('#' + toRevealId).trigger('click');
  }
}
```

In the code below, apart from modifying the `showSection` function - I've initially selected all the checkbox so as to align the toggle functionality. You will still need to work on the code to include functionality to select the next active tab when the active tab is hidden (like the if block above which is selecting the tab when the corresponding checkbox is selected).

Hope this helps.

```js
//Function to hide all siblings but leave the clicked one
function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
  $('#' + parentId).children().css('display', 'none');
  $('#' + toRevealId).css('display', 'block');
}

//Function to show the tab header and content when a checkbox is checked
function showSection(parentId, toRevealId) {
  $('#' + toRevealId).toggle('display');
  if ($('input[data-header=' + toRevealId + ']').is(':checked')) {
    $('#' + toRevealId).trigger('click');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //On clicking a tab header('Father', 'Mother', 'Brother')
  $('.tab-header').click(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('tab_active').siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
    var related_section = $(this).attr('data-section');
    hideAllChildrenButOne('relative_content', related_section);
  });

  //On changing any checkbox with name=relative[]
  $("input[name='relative[]']").change(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    //if (self.is(":checked")) {
    showSection('relative_tabs', self.attr('data-header'), self.attr('id'));
    //}
  });

});
```

```css
.relative_container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 45px 15px 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px 15px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .relative_container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

.relative_tabs {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 7px 0;
}

.relative_tabs:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.relative_tabs>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.relative_tabs>li>a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.relative_tabs>li.tab_active>a {
  color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.relative_content div {
  display: none;
}

.relative_content>div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Father" data-header="father-tab" checked></label>
  <label>Mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Mother" data-header="mother-tab" checked></label>
  <label>Brother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Brother" data-header="brother-tab" checked></label>
  <div class="relative_container">
    <div class="relative_header">
      <ul class="relative_tabs" id="relative_tabs">
        <li id="father-tab" data-section="Father_info" class="tab-header tab_active">
          <a>Father</a>
        </li>
        <li data-section="Mother_info" class="tab-header" id="mother-tab">
          <a>Mother</a>
        </li>
        <li data-section="Brother_info" class="tab-header" id="brother-tab">
          <a>Brother</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="relative_content" id="relative_content">
      <div class="tab-content active" id="Father_info">Father Info</div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="Mother_info">Mother Info</div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="Brother_info">Brother Info</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I replaced my JS code with your code, But something weird happened, The tabs are shown and when I check a checkbox the related tab is hidden and when I unchecked it becomes visible

Comment: Did you change the CSS/HTML too?

Comment: I edited the css and it almost working fine now, But the tabs gets on top of each other, So it needs to be inline-block

Comment: I changed the html to check the checkboxes by default

Comment: I'm facing 2 issues, When I check 2 checkboxes and uncheck one, The tab_active is not added to the checked one, Also when I check one and uncheck it the related content still visible and not hidden

Comment: Yes... These are valid issues which I didn't try to fix in the code above. If you are unable to fix this I can try it tomorrow (it's past midnight here so can't help right now)